# Using same kafka topic for two different environment

Tags: apache-kafka

**Scenario**: I have 2 microservices: MS1 and MS2. MS1 produces a message (say `msg1`) on `Kafka-topic1` and MS2 consumes `msg1` from the `Kafka-topic1`. MS1 and MS2 are deployed on the `DEV` environment and I bring up MS1 and MS2 on `local` as well.

**Question**: Using single `Kafka-topic1`, is there a way to ensure that:  
`msg1` produced by MS1 on the `DEV` environment is consumed by MS2 on the `DEV` environment? 
**AND** 
`msg1` produced by MS1 on the `local` environment is consumed by MS2 on the `local` environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you use different consumer groups for each environment, then those environments would read all messages independently, regardless of where the message was produced from.

If you want to fully isolate the producers, then you need a different topic